# How to know if an S3 bucket with Cross-Region Replication is fully replicated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication

I want to setup my S3 bucket to replicate in another region. Once it's fully replicated, I will make that bucket the main one (the idea is to migrate all data from one region to another). I know how to setup cross-region replication, but my problem is how can I know if the two buckets are 100% in sync? Since I'll need to know that to switch to that new bucket as the main one.

Any idea how to get that information?

Comment: I typed your question into Google and found this page, which says to use the Amazon S3 Inventory tool https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-status.html . I would also wonder if Cloudwatch has a metric.

Comment: I did find this page while I was searching this issue but I understand this status was only per-object, which would not be useful if I have millions of objects in the bucket. Instead I'm looking for a way to get the replication status of the whole bucket (say a number such as "99.6% of the bucket is replicated").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [AWS S3 inventory tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html). This creates a report which reports on the status of each object in the bucket. You can use AWS Athena or your preferred analysis mechanism to work out the replication status of the bucket.